# Two fragments and a button in Landscape mode in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am a beginner at Android Studio.
What I am trying here is to make two fragments and the second fragment has a button.

I was wondering why this XML code below is not working..

I got this notification..
Rendering Problems: A `<fragment>` tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.

My questions..

1. Is it okay to add Button element inside Fragment?
2. Can I add Frame inside Fragment as well?
3. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!--first fragment(left screen) -->
    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </fragment>


    <!--second fragment(right screen) -->
    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
    android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/article_new_fragment"
        android:text="OK!" />
     </fragment>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add button into the layout of the Fragment.

Comment: Your fragment should have a layout on it's own. Put your button in there. Not in the activity layout, like you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any view inside a fragment, just like you would do in an activity.
For what I can tell, that button is inside the activity layout.
So:

- Go To `com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment`
- Go to its method `onCreateView` (ctrl+F to look for it)
- It should have a return statement, something like
  `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);`

At this point, you should understand that this method returns the Fragment's layout.

- Go to the layout specified in that line (in this case, it would be
  R.layout.fragment_layout).
- Put in that layout the button, run the app and you should see it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

> Is it okay to add Button element inside Fragment?

Yes but in its own layout file. You define where is the layout file in you java fragment class.

> Can I add Frame inside Fragment as well?

If you mean frameLayout, yes but also in the layout file of the fragment.